# What is the preferred way to show/hide components in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the preferred way to toggle (show/hide) a component in React? To my knowledge, there are two ways to do this.

**Solution 1:**

Conditionally rendering the child component inside the `render()` method of the parent component.

```
{
    this.state.showUserModal ? 
    <UsereModal onClose={this.onModalClose} user={this.state.selectedUser}/>
    : null
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Using a property at the child component which inside its own `render()` method returns null or the children based on the boolean.

```
<UsereModal show={this.state.showUserModal} onClose={this.onModalClose} user={this.state.selectedUser}/>
```

The second solution causes to initialize the component only once (the constructor is called once) and the first solutions do not. I am having issues with this because in need to initialize my state based on the props inside the constructor, so I am forced to use solution 2. But what are the most React way to handle this?

Comment: This is primarly opinion based. For me, better is 1 method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases if the parent state or props are changed both the parent and the child components will be re-rendered. Hence there is no performance gain of the second solution. But if the child component should not be shown in the second case it will be mounted and rendered (but not shown). Taking it into account I would suggest to use the first case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist the DOM elements in the UI, you should go using style binding or class binding:

```
<UsereModal style={{display: this.state.showUserModal ? 'block' : 'none'}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first solution is better since you do not need to initiate UsereModal component with its own state that will control should component be shown or not. I prefer also jsx notation for conditional rendering

```
{
     this.state.showUserModal && <UsereModal onClose={this.onModalClose} user= 
     {this.state.selectedUser}/>
}
```