# What is the recommended way to show/hide child components in Angular?

Tags: angular, dom, html-rendering

The question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035963/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-show-hide-components-in-react-js), but there is no definitive answer there, and it relates to React, not Angular, so there is a chance that the answer would be different. Essentially, the question is "Is adding/removing elements from the DOM preferred over showing/hiding them?"
Given:

```
<app-parent>
    Zero or one of many child components displayed here.
</app-parent>
```

and if each of the children wraps itself in a modal thus:

```
<app-modal visible="isVisible"> Child n's content here </app-modal>
```

Which of the two ways is the recommended Angular way of going about this?

```
a.   <app-parent>
        <app-child1></app-child1>
        <app-child2></app-child2>
     </app-child>
```

And in the parent.component.ts file:

```
@ViewChild (Child1Component) child1: Child1Component;
...
showChild(childNumber: number) => {
   if (childNumber === 1) {
      this.child1.isVisible = true 
   } else {
      this.child2.isVisible = true 
   }
}
```

(isVisible will be set to false, to hide the modal and component, from within the child itself).

### OR

```
b.   <app-parent>
         <app-child1 *ngIf="showchild1"></app-child1>
         <app-child2 *ngIf="showchild2"></app-child2>
     </app-child>
```

And in the parent.component.ts file:

```
    showChild(childNumber: number) => {
       if (childNumber === 1) {
          this.showChild1 = true 
       } else {
          this.showChild2 = true 
       }
    }
```

In Case 'a' both/all child components are mounted and rendered, hidden, and not *shown* until a condition is met.  In Case 'b', one child component is inserted, visible, into the DOM when a condition is met, and removed accordingly (That part is not shown).

What is the recommended Angular way? Does the size of the child/ren component become a deciding factor?

Comment: you don need two variables only use variable and !variable (negation) in ngif directive

Comment: @WalterWhite Why are you assuming that one or the other child needs to show? I've said that zero or one child/ren could show.

Comment: i like b, but reading the summary it sounds like you're asking what is better adding/removing from the dom, or adding to the dom and making visible/invisible?

Comment: @JBoothUA, yes, that's what I'm asking. If each component is tiny, it might not make a difference, but if huge, and more than just two, it would. Is there Angular style guidance on this?

Comment: "preferred" pretty much puts the question squarely into opinion-based category. If you just want to know if there is official guidance, well a) you can search their site as well as anyone, but b) adding that requisite will put the question back into objective-land.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, and your summary section

> Case 'a' both/all child components are mounted and rendered, hidden,
> and not shown until a condition is met. In Case 'b', one child
> component is inserted, visible, into the DOM when a condition is met,
> and removed accordingly (That part is not shown).

I believe it really comes down to a) do we want components in the DOM and hidden/unhidden or b) do we want to add/remove things to the DOM.

And for what it's worth, I believe the answer is actually a case-by-case basis type of thing.

There is a good bit of scenarios where you want the component in the DOM and (for example) updating in the background based on events or user input, or running some other sort of logic.  And even though this isn't shown at all times, it needs to be present in the DOM or it would "miss" the event or user input and when it was made visible it would not be in sync with the rest of the application.

I've also been in a good bit of scenarios where you do not want the component to be in the DOM.  Lets say there is sensitive information that you only want to show after the user "unlocks" a portion of the application.  It would be a security risk to have it in the DOM and hidden as someone with dev skills would be able to find it by inspecting the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Go with option b. Because this way component will be reinitialised every time it shows and destroyed otherwise and save some rerenders because of change detection. Unless you want component to only ever be created once.

Also just to point out: I think option a needs ContentChild not ViewChild.